# Insertar un objeto en MongoDB con AJAX

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, mongodb

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito insertar en mongodb como se ve en el primer objeto pero cuando inserto se hace como la segunda forma. Estoy enviando la petición de la siguiente forma:

```
                var obj = {
                    type: "Point",
                    coordinates: [[lng,lat]]
                  };
```

AJAX

```
   $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/insertPlace",
  data: _geometry,
  success: function (data) {
        console.log('ya');
  }
```

});

API

```
router.post('/insertPlace', function(req, res, next) { 
  var geometry = req.body;

  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err,client){
   if (err) throw err;

   console.log("Connected correctly to server");
   const db = client.db(dbName);


  db.collection("places").insertOne(geometry,function(err,result){
       if (err){
        console.log(err.message);
        throw err;
       } 
       console.log(result);
       res.json(result);
       client.close();
   });

});

});
```

La verdad, desconozco como es posible que MongoDB trata los documentos de tipo geometry, ya que necesito buscar mediante geolocalización un punto en específico.

Muchas gracias por todo y les deseo buenas noches

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema lo tienes en la forma en la que estás declarando el objeto que envías a tu servidor.

Si te das cuenta, la estructura del objeto que pones en tu pregunta no es la misma que deseas obtener:

```
var obj = {
    type: "Point",
    coordinates: [[lng,lat]]
};
```

Produce el siguiente documento en MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id": "5d19ed0eca4247150b201f1b",
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
        [12345, 54321]
    ]
}
```

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para obtener el documento que deseas, debes modificar el objeto que estás enviando al servidor, el mismo debería ser de la siguiente forma:

```
var obj = {
    geometry: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [lng,lat]
    }
}
```

El mismo genera el siguiente documento en MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id": "5d19ed0eca4247150b201f1b",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [12345, 54321]
    }
}
```

Para cambiar el tipo de variables que se almacenan en la base de datos, debes realizar el `cast` de las mismas antes de la inserción. Si lo dejas tal como lo tienes actualmente, los valores `lat` y `lng` serán almacenados como un tipo `string`. Por lo que se ve en tu imagen, deseas los mismos en tipo `double`.

Una forma muy básica de hacerlo sería la siguiente:

```
router.post('/insertPlace', function(req, res, next) { 
  var document = req.body;
  // el objecto 'document' contiene una propiedad 'geometry' que a su vez tiene un campo 'coordinates' el cual almacena un array con las coordenadas
  document.geometry.coordinates[0] = Number.parseFloat(document.geometry.coordinates[0]);
  document.geometry.coordinates[1] = Number.parseFloat(document.geometry.coordinates[1]);
  // en este caso no estoy verificando si los valores de coordenadas son validos para que el método 'parseFloat()' no arroje errores.
  //Sin embargo es bueno realizar la verificación
  // el resto de tu middleware aqui
  // ...
});
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Recibo un error de tipo 500 al implementar tu solución, Haciendo un log de la variable document, obtengo lo siguiente:

[Object: null prototype] {
  'geometry[type]': 'Point',
  'geometry[coordinates][]': [ '-101.71157582164307', '21.15136522260949' ] }

Comment: Cuando realizas la solicitud AJAX, pasas la siguiente data: `data: _geometry`. ¿Exactamente qué contiene dicha variable (`_geometry`)?

Comment: [Object: null prototype] {
  'geometry[type]': 'Point',
  'geometry[coordinates][]': [ '-101.6644118583252', '21.17313676228592' ] }